# PowerShell launcher

Tags: command-line, unity, launcher, gnome-terminal, powershell

I am setting up a demo Ubuntu 16.04 devbox and I wanted to create a launcher entry for PowerShell that uses the default gnome-terminal but with the canonical PowerShell colors and icon on the launcher. I have already created a profile for PS colors, but I don't know how to tell the launcher to use it.

I got started by copying the gnome-terminal.desktop, but I do not see from where it knows that bash will be the default shell. I do not want to change that system to PS, because hell will break loose.

**Edit until solution:**

This is how my .desktop looks like at the moment:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=PowerShell
Comment=PowerShell Core
Keywords=shell;prompt;command;commandline;cmd;
Exec=gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=PowerShell --command=/usr/bin/powershell
#Icon=/home/mnagy/Képek/Desired-State-Configuration-intro.png
Icon=/home/mnagy/Képek/11524380.png
Type=Application
Categories=System;TerminalEmulator;
StartupNotify=true
#X-GNOME-SingleWindow=false
#OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
```

The problem is now, that when I launch this, the window does not appear under its own icon, but pops open a normal terminal icon on the left bar. I can spawn new windows with the right coloring and right shell, but it's kinda annoying to have two sets of icons for the same thing.

Comment: It is not within the launcher properties. That's something you have to tell to gnome terminal to execute. So you want to use -e flag in the Exec= line. Same goes for profile. You can use the specif flag for that

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but if I modify the file to have

TryExec=gnome-terminal -e /usr/bin/powershell
Exec=gnome-terminal -e /usr/bin/powershell

it fails to launch whatsoever.